# move multiple folders to new folder and zip the folder using tar

Tags: shell

I want a shell script to move multiple folders to a new folder and zip or compress that folder. Can anybody please help me out?
I have a file called dirfile where directory names are stored which are to be moved to a new directory.

```
#!/bin/usr/sh
while read line; do
Unix_Array[$counter]=$line;
let counter=counter+1;
echo $counter;
done < dirfile
echo {Unix_Array[0]}
for line in [Unix_Array]
do
tar -czvf "$x.tar.gz" "$x"
done
```

Comment: «Zip using tar»... Like walking using a car?

Comment: buddy use your brain to answer the question. hope you got my point.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have looks more or less OK (though I wonder why you need two loops--it seems you could do it all at once without the intermediate array).  But you're using `tar -c` when you should be using `tar -r` to add content to the file rather than creating a new tar file each time.